# Evaluating the Volume of a Cupola-Shaped Set by Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

> Let $f(x,y) = 1 - \tfrac{x^2}{4} - y^2$ and
>   $$
> \Omega = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon f(x,y) \ge 0 \rbrace.
> $$
>   Compute the volume of the set
>   $$
> A = \lbrace (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon (x,y) \in \Omega, 0 \le z \le f(x,y) \rbrace.
> $$

My idea is to slice the set along the $z$-axis, obtaining a set $E_z$ - in fact, an ellipse - and computing the volume as
$$
\int_0^1 \int_{E_z} dxdydz
$$

However, I am stuck finding a way to describe $E_z$. What is the best strategy to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this parameterization for the whole $3$ dimensional space

$$\begin{align}
x&=2u\cos v \\
y&=u \sin v \\
z&=w
\end{align} \qquad 0 \le u \lt \infty, \quad 0 \le v \lt 2\pi, \quad -\infty \lt w \lt \infty$$

then the integral for volume will be

$$V=\int_{v=0}^{2\pi}\int_{u=0}^{1}\int_{w=0}^{1-u^2}\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}dw\,du\,dv$$

where

$$\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}
& \frac{\partial x}{\partial w} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
& \frac{\partial y}{\partial w} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
& \frac{\partial z}{\partial w} 
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
2\cos v & -2u \sin v & 0 \\
\sin v & u \cos v & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}=
2u$$

is the jacobian.

Comment: Thank you. Should perhaps be $u$ ranging from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-z^2}$?

Comment: @uomoinverde: The range of $u$ is selected such that it covers the whole $xy$ plane. But for your integral $0 \le u \le 1$. :)

Comment: @uomoinverde: Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Ok. Basically, I've found out that my first attempt put me on the right path, but didn't trust myself. :-) Thank you again.

Comment: @uomoinverde: You are welcome. :)